# How to send data transparently using a GSM modem?

Tags: serial-port, remote-access, gsm, modem, telecommunication

I want to send data to a remote modem+device using a local GSM modem attached to my PC.
At our customers premises with a local modem server it works as follows:

```
16:16:55.731 COM202 : » A
16:16:55.731 COM202 : » T
16:16:55.731 COM202 : » &
16:16:55.731 COM202 : » F
16:16:55.731 COM202 : » 0
16:16:55.731 COM202 : » ^M
16:16:55.731 COM202 : | COM Port Control negotiated (RFC-2217)
16:16:55.856 COM202 : « ^M^JOK^M^J
16:16:56.075 COM202 : » A
16:16:56.075 COM202 : » T
16:16:56.075 COM202 : » E
16:16:56.075 COM202 : » 0
16:16:56.075 COM202 : » V
16:16:56.075 COM202 : » 1
16:16:56.075 COM202 : » X
16:16:56.075 COM202 : » 1
16:16:56.075 COM202 : » &
16:16:56.075 COM202 : » K
16:16:56.075 COM202 : » 0
16:16:56.075 COM202 : » ^M
16:16:56.075 COM202 : « A
16:16:56.091 COM202 : « TE
16:16:56.106 COM202 : « 0V1X1&K0^M
16:16:56.216 COM202 : « ^M^JOK^M^J
16:16:56.435 COM202 : | RTS: 1 
16:16:56.435 COM202 : | FlushTX
16:16:56.435 COM202 : | FlushRX
16:16:56.435 COM202 : | RTS: 1 
16:16:56.435 COM202 : | DTR: 1 
16:16:56.435 COM202 : | FlushTX
16:16:56.435 COM202 : | FlushRX
16:16:56.935 COM202 : » ATDT907315XXXXX
16:16:56.935 COM202 : » ^M
16:17:29.951 COM202 : « ^M^JCONNECT ^M^J
16:17:29.951 COM202 : | CD: 1 
16:17:30.451 COM202 : » ~ ^J^@^B^@#^G“û^F~
16:17:31.670 COM202 : « ~ #^G^@^B^@#slX€^T^E^B^@€^F^B^@€^G^D
16:17:31.686 COM202 : « ^@^@^@^G^H^D^@^@^@^A^C2~
16:17:31.811 COM202 : » ~ G^@^B^@#^G^P!Yææ^@`6¡^I^F^G`…t^E^H^A^AŠ^B^G€‹^G`…
```

After some pre-settings the number is dialed using `ATDT907315XXXXX`, we get back `CONNECT` and can proceed to send data transparently to the remote station.

Using a dumb WAVECOM modem I tried to reproduce the call from my office. However, when I try ATDXXXX I get NO CARRIER:

```
ATD+0664881XXXXX
NO CARRIER
```

On the other hand, I can use the ";" to setup a voice connection, it works. But in this case I cannot send data transparently.

Q: What is the right way to send data transparently using a modem?

And how should I choose baud rate? The remote device after the remote modem requires 9600 baud, but to send AT commands to my modem it works only with 115200 baud. So even when I manage to establish an ADT connection, it would be wrong baud rate.

Comment: So, let me understand. The reported serial log is you customer's one, and not yours, right? In this case, do you reproduce the exact AT commands sequence? What is the modem's response to the command `AT+FCLASS?`

Comment: Also the response to `AT+FCLASS=?` might be useful.